# Capture the progress percentage of curl but without the decimal numbers

Tags: regex, bash, curl, grep

This question is particularly a regular expression issue.

I'd like to capture the progress percentage of `curl` command in `bash` using `grep`, but excluding the floating point numbers. The goal is to present these captured values to a `dialog`'s `--gauge` option.

Here's what I've achieved so far:

```
$ curl -#LO "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg" 2>&1 | stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' | grep -Eo '[0-9.]*'
```

The above example command will output something like this:

```
3.8
20.1
47.1
93.4
100.0
```

But I'm expecting results like this:

```
3
20
47
93
100
```

I've searched for a regex to this, but I didn't find any good results.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use `.` as field separator and get the first field using `cut` or `awk` or even `grep -o` on the current output you have.. if you have `GNU grep` with PCRE, then you can use lookahead to do it with one command

Comment: @Sundeep You are right sir! I forgot the `cut` command can remove texts with it's `-d` option. If you reply an example, I'll mark it as an answer :) **Edit:** Tttthank yoouuu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cut your output using . as separator

```
$ curl -#LO "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg" 2>&1 | stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' | grep -Eo '[0-9.]*' | cut -f1 -d\.
```

Comment: I noticed that this example will produce buffering issue on large files, so what I did is prepend the `stdbuf` to each pipe: `curl -#LO ${url} 2>&1 | stdbuf -o L tr '\r' '\n' | stdbuf -o L grep -Eo '[0-9.]*' | stdbuf -o L cut -d '.' -f 1`